# How to set windows path regex pattern?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

I have a list of paths, and I need a match for all starting with `C:\Program Files\_folder_\_folder_\etc` and then having any amount and any type of character a windows path can use.
This is how I approach, though I guess this only allows alpanumeric characters:

```
string pathPattern = @"C:\Program Files\_folder_\_folder_\etc[0-z]*";
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(myList[n], pathPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    {
        //some action
    }
```

Comment: you mean this part `C:\Program Files\_folder_\_folder_\etc` doen't change in path?

Comment: Indeed, that is a pre-defined part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `C:\Program Files\_folder_\_folder_\etc` is the pre-defined part. I think you can do this without `Regex` like this using `Contains`

```
if(pathPattern.Contains(@"C:\Program Files\_folder_\_folder_\etc"))
{
    //some action
}
```

Edit 1: You can do `ToLower()` on `pathPattern`

```
var ss = pathPattern.ToLower().Contains(@"C:\Program Files\_folder_\_folder_\etc".ToLower());
```

Comment: Thank you again. I also found this regarding the case sensitivity issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Answer (score 1):

**1. If you want your path should starts with :**

> C:\Program Files\

then use below code :

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(code, @"[cC]{1}\:\\Program Files\\.*"))
{
   \\ Do Your work
}
```

**2. If you want your path should starts with :**

> c:\Program Files_folder__folder_\

then use below code :

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(code, @"[cC]{1}\:\\Program Files\\_folder_\\_folder_\\.*"))
{
    \\ Do Your work
}
```

**Description:**

1. **cC{1}** : Check for C drive (c:)
2. **@"[cC]{1}\:\Program Files\** : Check for C:\Program Files
3. **.*** : Checks for any folder after C:\Program Files

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.])+$
```

Sample Code

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files\_folder_\_folder_\";
string pathPattern = @"^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.])+$"

if(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(path, pathPattern)){
    //It matches the regex
}
else
{
    //it doesnot matches the regex
}
```

Works for these:

```
\\test\test$\TEST.xls
\\server\share\folder\myfile.txt
\\server\share\myfile.txt
\\123.123.123.123\share\folder\myfile.txt
c:\folder\myfile.txt
c:\folder\myfileWithoutExtension
```

Comment: could you explain this regex..? As someone who is not a regex expert I would love to see what it actually does

Comment: Yes please let us know what it does, and which characters does it match exactly, and how to merge this with the pre-defined part of path in the begining.

Comment: You don't understand what I want... The path can be literally anything, and the patter should be 'C:\Program Files\_folder_\_folder_\+AnyCharacter'

Comment: So you want to match all the list with the pattern and return true if all of them matches and return false if not. Is is something like that